# SQL Return X rows depending on the value within same row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wish to return duplicate rows of data depending on a value in that same row.

Take the following table...

```
customer | noOfConnections
A        | 1
B        | 1
C        | 2
D        | 1
```

I would like some sql to return this...

```
customer | connectionNumber
A        | 1
B        | 1
C        | 1
C        | 2
D        | 1
```

Is there a way??

Thanks

Comment: There is a way. With SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numbers table, yayyy!

Have a search around for a script. Alternatively [here's one I made earlier](http://gvee.co.uk/files/sql/dbo.numbers%20&%20dbo.calendar.sql).

```
SELECT your_table.customer
     , your_table.noOfConnections
     , numbers.number As connectionNumber
FROM   your_table
 INNER
  JOIN dbo.numbers
    ON numbers.number BETWEEN 1 AND your_table.noOfConnections
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;with  cTE as
(

select   'A' customer, 1 noOfConnections union all
select  'B', 1 union all
select  'C', 2 union all
select  'D', 1 
)
, CTE1 as
(
select customer,noOfConnections from cte where noOfConnections>1
union all
select a.customer,a.noOfConnections-1 from cte A inner join cte1 B 
on a.customer=b.customer and b.noOfConnections=a.noOfConnections

)
select * from cte1 
union all
select * from cte where noOfConnections=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
--Drop table Table1

CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([cust] varchar(1), [cn] int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
VALUES
    ('A', 1),
    ('B', 1),
    ('C', 1),
    ('C', 2),
    ('D', 1),
    ('E', 4);

with cte as(
    select Max(cn) CN,
                    cust 
    from Table1
    group by cust
    union all 
    select c1.Cn-1 CN,c1.cust from cte c1 join table1 T1 on c1.cust=t1.cust
    where c1.cn-1>0
)
select * from cte
order by cust,cn
```

Answer (score 0):

CTEs with Table-Values functions work nicely here. Just replace 10 by the max number you can encounter.

```
WITH q AS
(
    SELECT  1 AS maxNum
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  maxNum + 1
    FROM    q
    WHERE   maxNum < 10
)
SELECT Customer, maxNum as connectionNumber
FROM Customers
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM q WHERE maxNum<=noOfConnections) temp
```

Edit: you can rework that CTE to extract the max from your table, see the answer above:
So here would be my solution:

```
WITH q AS
(
    SELECT Max(noOfConnections) AS maxNum
    FROM Customers
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  maxNum - 1
    FROM    q
    WHERE   maxNum > 1
)
SELECT Customer, maxNum as connectionNumber
FROM Customers
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM q WHERE maxNum<=noOfConnections) temp
```